# How to switch namespace in lens

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using [lens kubernetes](https://k8slens.dev/) I searched and tried a lot but I didn't find any way to switch between namespaces. is there any option to do so ?
to clarify it in vscode extension you can switch between namespaces easily by right clicking on a namespace listed and then selecting `use Namespace` option [image: switch to ns in vs code]

also in kubectl using this command :

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=my-namespace
```

but how can we do it in lens ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember correctly there is a dropdown on the top right corner which you can use to select the namespace from.

Here is a screenshot from a blog that shows this dropdown:

[image: Select Namespace]

Comment: This is correct. You can also CTRL/CMD + click on multiple namespaces in the list if you need to view the contents of more than one namespace at the same time

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to add the namespace in the cluster settings of OpenLens.

Clusters ➡️ select cluster ➡️ settings ➡️ Namespace ➡️ add your namespace